# my.confファイルの[client]グループと[mysql]グループについて

Tags: mysql

**Q1.my.confファイルの[client]グループと[mysql]グループはそれぞれどういう役割があるのでしょうか？**
・[mysqld]グループはサーバに関することを記述するセクションと認識しているのですが、[client]グループは、クライアント全般に関する記述を行うとは限らない？
・[mysql]グループはまた別の話ですか？

---

**Q2.utf8mb4をmy.confファイルで設定する場合**
・[mysqld][client][mysqldump]の3つ全部に記述する必要がある？
・[mysql]セクションには記述しなくても良い？

[[mysqld] グループおよび [mysql] グループは、それぞれ mysqld サーバーおよび mysql クライアントプログラムに適用されます](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/option-files.html)

---

**環境**
・MySQL5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的には実行するプログラム（コマンド名）のグループが参照されます。各プログラムがどのオプショングループを参照するかは `--help` オプションで確認できます。（mysqldの場合は `--verbose --help` とする必要があります）

`client` グループは `mysql` コマンドを始めとする複数のクライアント プログラムから参照されます。`mysql` グループは `mysql` コマンドのみが参照します。

utf8mb4 を設定するのは `[mysqld]` `[client]` だけでいいと思いますが、重複して書かれても問題は無いと思います。